# Upload multiple files with maintaining Index ( position at which file was uploaded) in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, struts2, struts-action

I have scenario that, I want to upload multiple files, In which User may or may not upload files, And I want to maintain Index at which position user has uploaded file and want to save file with that index as Name

I referred  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17050230/3425489  , In my case I don't want to create new class, so not referred Accepted solution

till now In my **Action Class** I have

```java
File upload [];
String uploadContentType []
String uploadFileName []
```

**getters and setters**

In my jsp I tried

```xml
<input type="file" name="upload">
```

but I'm able to get uploaded files only, **not able to maintain index**

also tried

```xml
<input type="file" name="upload[0]">
<input type="file" name="upload[1]">
<input type="file" name="upload[2]">
```

with this case, I'm **not able to setProperties** in my Action class

**----Updated----**

You can refer my **Model** [Struts 2 : Unable to access Model properties in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40583282/3425489)

For your every ProcessSolutionStep, I want to maintain, which file is uploaded for particular step,

i.e. User may upload file for **step 1** and **step 5**, skipping middle steps, and in view.

I want to display file uploaded for particular step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is How I solved my Problem:

```html
    <tr>
    <td> Step 1 :
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="isFileUpload" id="id-is-file-upload-0" value="0">
        <textarea id="id-solution-0" name="processSolutionSteps" rows="2" cols="50" maxlength="200" class="class-text-area class-text-area-not-blank"></textarea>
        <!-- <input type="text" id="id-solution-0" name="processSolution" maxlength="30" size="35"> -->
        <p id="id-process-solution-counter-0"></p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="file" id="id-file-0" name="uploads">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Step 2 :
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="isFileUpload" id="id-is-file-upload-1" value="0">
        <textarea id="id-solution-1" name="processSolutionSteps" rows="2" cols="50" maxlength="200" class="class-text-area class-text-area-not-blank"></textarea>
        <!-- <input type="text" id="id-solution-1" name="processSolution" size="35"> -->
        <p id="id-process-solution-counter-1"></p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="file" id="id-file-1" name="uploads">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Step 3 :
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="isFileUpload" id="id-is-file-upload-2" value="0">
        <textarea id="id-solution-2" name="processSolutionSteps" rows="2" cols="50" maxlength="200" class="class-text-area class-text-area-not-blank"></textarea>
        <!-- <input type="text" id="id-solution-2" name="processSolution" size="35"> -->
        <p id="id-process-solution-counter-2"></p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="file" id="id-file-2" name="uploads">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I just post few sample code of my `<tr>` tag

I have maintained one **hidden field** `isFileUpload` with inital value **0** , as many no. of my `<input type="file">`, 
After uploading file, on its **change** event I changed value of `isFileUpload` to **1** as

```
$('#id-solution-table').on('change', 'input[type=file]', function () {
    $('#id-is-file-upload-'+$(this).prop("id").split("-")[2]).val(1);
});
```

And In my Action Class I have this code

Depending upon values of `isFileUpload` i.e. I have checked it with **1**,

Means I have uploded file **at this index position** and Mapped with uploaded file array which is `uploads`

```
private File [] uploads;
private String [] uploadsFileName;
private String [] uploadsContentType;
private short isFileUpload [];

try {
    int fileIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.isFileUpload.length; i++) {
        if( this.isFileUpload[i] == 1 ) {
            System.out.println(" index    "+i+ " isFileUpload "+this.isFileUpload[i]);
            System.out.println("Index       "+i+ "     "+this.uploadsFileName[ fileIndex ]);
            String filePath = path;
            new File(filePath).mkdirs();
            FileUtils.copyFile(this.uploads[ fileIndex ], new File(filePath+"/"+i+"."+FilenameUtils.getExtension(this.uploadsFileName[ fileIndex ])));
            ++fileIndex;
        }
    }
} catch(Exception exception) {
    addActionError("Some files not uploaded.");
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: hidden fields are good, they can use indexed property names ;)

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a new class (that is one way, if you prefer to encapsulate every object singularly), just use `List`s:

```java
public class Upload extends ActionSupport{

    private List<File> files;
    private List<String> filesContentType;
    private List<String> filesFileName;

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */           

    public String execute() throws Exception{
        System.out.print("\n\n---------------------------------------");
        int i=0;
        for (File file : files){
            System.out.print("\nFile ["+i+"] ");
            System.out.print("; name:"         + filesFileName.get(i));
            System.out.print("; contentType: " + filesContentType.get(i));
            System.out.print("; length: "      + file.length());
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("\n---------------------------------------\n");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

Use the `multiple` attribute and don't forget the right `enctype`:

```xml
<s:form action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <s:file name="files" multiple="multiple" />
    <s:submit value="Upload files" />
</s:form>
```

Comment: thank you for response, but I don't want to select files at Once, I want stepwise selection ,plz check update

Comment: One more try out I can do is that , I make array of hidden field, and set its vale to **0** or **1**, for particular **Step** depend upon file upload or not, check its value at my Action and do process Uploaded files as well...plz suggest me

Comment: So just do `<input type="file" name="upload">`
`<input type="file" name="upload">`
`<input type="file" name="upload">`. Does it work like this ? Isn't the index retained by the List ?

Comment: I did this, but if I have **5** `<input>`, and I upload 2 files, suppose at `<input>` **2** and **5**, I got only uploaded files , i.e. 2 only

Comment: IF you want to differentiate them, just give every input a different name. IF you don't want to differentiate them, then there should be no difference between 1-2 and 2-5, for example. Using the same name with a different index for inputs that you want to differentiate is just wrong.

Comment: I am implementing as told You in my **comment**, will let you know soon after completion...

Comment: @ Andrea Ligios I have posted answer, sorry for late  , plz suggest any improvement

Comment: You're good to go. Please consider upvoting the answer if it helped, and accept your own if that's what you've finally used