# How to find missing parameter OR wrong param [No result defined for action and result input] in Struts2

Tags: java, validation, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I have following code snippets:

**From `struts.xml`:**

```
<action name="list-process-solution" class="actions.ProcessSolutionAction" method="listProcessSolutions">
    <interceptor-ref name="store">
        <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    <result name="success">process_solution_list.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">process_solution_list.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">Error.jsp</result>
    <result name="login">Login.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="delete-process-solution" class="actions.ProcessSolutionAction" method="crudProcessSolution">
    <interceptor-ref name="store">
        <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">list-process-solution</param>
        <param name="nsec">${nsec}</param>
    </result>
    <result name="error">Error.jsp</result>
    <result name="login">Login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

After deleting I'm redirecting to List Page ( same again Page )

*But* I'm getting result as `INPUT` don't know where I'm wrong.

**I have configured this link for delete**:

```
<s:url var="varDeletePS" action="delete-process-solution">
    <s:param name="nsec">
        <s:property value="nsec"/>
    </s:param>
    <s:param name="processId">
        <s:property value="processId"/>
    </s:param>
    <s:param name="opType">
        <s:property value="2" />
    </s:param>
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{varDeletePS}" id="id-delete-PS-link" cssClass="class-delete">
    Delete
</s:a>
```

**In action, I have these fields with getters and setters**:

```
private ProcessSolution processSolution;
private short opType;
private String nsec;
```

For Model `ProcessSolution` refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40583282/3425489)

**My Question is:**

How to handle result name `INPUT` here ? I don't know which parameter is wrong ?

**Update :**

How to continue with same request after `redirectAction`, so I will have my request parameters ?

How to identify which field having error ?

**UPDATE 2 :**

My `delete-process-solution` executing properly but on result `SUCCESS` , and `redirectAction` to `list-process-solution`, I'm getting result as `INPUT`.

Comment: You don't have `redirectAction` for `input` result. Use `<s:actionerror />` and/or `<s:fielderror />` tags in `input` result page. You can also enable devMode.

Comment: @AleksandrM , I'm not doing any validation for input, btw Is there any way to find which field having problem with setter (setting in my action class) ..?

Comment: plz check UPDATE 2

Comment: Yes, there is. Follow my advice. Use tags in jsp and turn the dev mode on.

Comment: I have turned on `devMode` and which tags to use ?

Answer (score 0):

`INPUT` result is returned if you have validation errors. Create validation method prefixed for each action in the action class and add `INPUT` result to the action config.

```
<result name="input">Login.jsp</result>
```

---

You might have validation errors which results `INPUT`, but the action is not executed and message isn't set. If you want to prevent the action from validation you can configure the action to *exclude* the method from [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html) or use the solution above.

As far as `validation` interceptor implements a method filter interceptor you can do it in `struts.xml`. Or just add `@SkipValidation` annotation on the method.

```
@SkipValidation
public String crudProcessSolution(){//used this method for delete   

//<action name="delete-process-solution" class="actions.ProcessSolutionAction" method="crudProcessSolution">
```

Comment: Yes I know  result name `input` is returned, but How to find for which **parameter** I'm having problem..? ty for reply

Comment: I already, have this line in my xml  `<result name="input">process_solution_list.jsp</result>`

Comment: the parameter is the same which is sent to the action, you populate it to the action and it's available in JSP from the value stack.

Comment: in my action `delete-process-solution` i'm using `type="redirectAction"` for result `name="success"`, I think my request parameters are **lost** , **How to continue with request after `redirectAction` ?**

Comment: After `redirectAction` result you don't need any parameter, but if you have some other parameters that should persist on the list view then use `redirect` result.

Comment: @shantaram You can exclude the action method from validation.